# Seeking LiDAR data for Palawan (Philippines)?

Tags: data, lidar, philippines

Is there any public or private sources of LIDAR data for San Paul river in Palawan (Philippines)?

Searching online has not lead me to any sources, and I am unsure how the commercial world of LIDAR works. I'm speleo and I would like to know better this area.

Comment: You may want to ask a similar question on the [opendata.se] (Beta) Stack Exchange.

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4535

Comment: Do you really need LiDAR data or do you just need a digital elevation model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at the SRTM (Shuttle Radar Topography Mission) elevation data - global 30m coverage. Earth Explorer has a shapefile download of SRTM water body data.